# W3C CSS Validator error with required attribute

Tags: css, html, validation

I'm getting the following error in the W3C CSS 3 Validator:

> Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :required

Required is a HTML5 input attribute. My CSS works in IE10, Google Chrome and Firefox.

This is my CSS:

```
#reserved input:required {background:#eaeae6;}
#reserved select:required {background:#eaeae6;}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<section id="reserved">
    <select id="hab" name="hab" title="Study or Apartment" required>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50" style="width: 200px;" title="Name and Surname" required/>
</section>
```

Doesn't W3C recognize the required attribute like a standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3 includes the [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) API. Selectors 3 does not include the `:required` selector.

`:required` was introduced in [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#opt-pseudos). Browsers support it, but it isn't part of the CSS3 specification and so will fail in a CSS3 validator.

Comment: +1 ... missed the part were it failed in css3 validation. it will fail with HTML validation if using XHTML though. Nothing wrong with leaving it written here. :)

Comment: Actually, `:required` first appeared in css3-ui, before being promoted to the Selectors 4 spec. This is confirmed by sel4 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#overview). That said, sel4 is part of CSS3 anyway (despite the "4") so either way it should validate - the validator just needs to be updated, unless it considers that part of css3-ui non-canon for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer lonesomeday.

I change my css and create a class instead of the required pseudo-class like this:

```
#reserved .required-class {background: #eaeae6;}

<input class="required-class" type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}" style="width: 200px;" title="email" required/>
```

With this change, now I've passed the W3C Validator :D